# Why is the $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ raising operator defined as a commutator

Tags: group-theory, operator-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying on Georgi's "Lie Algebras in Particle Physics" ([here](http://mural.uv.es/rusanra/Lie%20Algebras%20in%20Particle%20Physics%202%C2%AA%20ed%20-%20From%20Isospin%20to%20Unified%20Theories%20(Georgi,%201999).pdf)) (eq. 8.29) and have trouble understanding the following: $\\$
given that a raising (or lowering) operator acting on a weight $\mu$ is $E_\alpha|\mu>=|\mu+\alpha>$, why is $E_{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}=[E_{\alpha_1},E_{\alpha_2}]$?
The book makes the example $|[E_{\alpha_1},E_{\alpha_2}]>=E_{\alpha_1}|E_{\alpha_2}>=...=E_{\alpha_1}|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}>\propto|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}>=|E_{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}>$. Why is the last equality true?

The only thing i thought of is because upon inserting $\alpha_1+\alpha_2$ in the master formula one gets the right $p$ and $q$ given a weight $\mu$. If this is the reason, how do you generalise it without mechanically checking

Comment: $E_{\alpha_1}E_{\alpha_2}$ does not come from the Lie algebra because it is not closed under composition. It is closed under commutators though.

Comment: The state $|E_j\rangle$ should actually be understood as the adjoint representation, so naturally $E_i|E_j\rangle = |[E_i, E_j]\rangle$ (because that's what the adjoint representation means). See Section $6.2$. It's a clever abuse of notation, really.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I (think) I fully understand the notation (which I find brilliant), the major problem I'm having is with the last equality in the chain: why is the $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}>$ denoted as $E_{\alpha_1+\alpha_2}$?

Comment: Check out $6.8$. It makes the connection between $X_a|X_b\rangle$ and $|[X_a,X_b]\rangle$. The connection with $|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ then comes from what happens with raising operators.

Comment: Use `\langle` for the left angle bracket and `\rangle` for the right angle bracket, instead of `<` and `>`.